# ASP.NET: asp:LinkButton with Javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, linkbutton

i want to use an `asp:LinkButton`, since it looks like a link, yet also has server-side Click handler.

But the web-server seems unable to detect if javascript is disabled on the client, and doesn't render into a mechanism that still works.

Is it possible to have a link that looks like a link, but has server-side OnClick event handler?

---

### Answer

The answer is no, but below are some workaround ideas. Accepted the one with non-zero up-votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use CSS to style a button to look like a link, but this will be very much browser dependant, depending on the CSS implementation.

---

**Edit:** I feel compelled to complete my answer since it's been accepted.

An `asp:LinkButton` renders to an HTML link, and as such cannot **post** to a web page; but can only make **get** requests. To work around this MS use JavaScript to action the post. This is not possible however if Javascript is disabled.

`asp:Button` and `asp:ImageButton` are different. They submit the HTML form by posting to a web page (or get depending on the form attributes) by using true HTML form elements. So these will work without JS intervention.

Some browsers will allow CSS styling to style a button to look like a link, and as such this can be used to work around the issue.

Comment: A more complete version would have some sample code - otherwise it just begs another SO question called "How do i use CSS and Javascript" to create a button that looks like a link.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea:

Render an input button and use javascript to change it into a link. The button would work for non-javascript enabled browser and become a link for those who have javascript.

Comment: Great idea, progressive enhancement!

Answer (score 2):

With anything like this in ASP.Net I'd usually render the control, along with an "accessible control" that's hidden with JavaScript. So in this case it would render a LinkButton (hidden by default via styles), and a normal button, with some javascript registered to hide the Button and show the LinkButton.

It's quite a common workaround for ASP.Net control that don't play nicely without javascript, or when you need "Autopostback" without Javascript.

Comment: Some sample code to explain what you're talking about would be good.

Answer (score 0):

There is no INPUT type which will look like a link.  If you want to use a link to perform an INPUT type activity on a web page, it will have to navigate to the same page that you are on.

You can pass a query string variable with the link, and respond to that.  It won't act exactly like a postback, instead it will just navigate to the same page that you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, what you're asking for is possible.

You have to to configure the control like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnRequestReview" Text="[ Request Plan Review ]" OnCommand="lbtnRequestReview_Command" CommandName="cmd" CommandArgument="0" CausesValidation="false" runat="server"/>
```

and put this in the code-behind:

```
protected void lbtnRequestReview_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
           //...
        }
```

You can find more detailed information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname.aspx).