# ASP.NET OnClick | Fire without JavaScript Enabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick

I have a basic form that fires using an ASP.NET `OnClick` event such as:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Submit" CssClass="submit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="Submit_Click" ValidationGroup="email"/>
```

Is there a way to fire this if someone has JS turned off? If not what is my next best alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a relevant link: [ASP.NET: asp:LinkButton with Javascript disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480498/asp-net-asplinkbutton-with-javascript-disabled)